# How to pass unicode VM arguments with eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode

I'm not able to read unicode strings passed as VM arguments, if I launch the process from Eclipse IDE.

For example:

```
ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
commands.add("java");
commands.add("-classpath");
commands.add("bin");
commands.add("-Dprop=ÁÉÍÓÚ");
commands.add("test.ReadProp");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
Process process = pb.start();
BufferedReader in;
String line;
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(line);
```

With *test.ReadProp*

```
String prop = System.getProperty("prop");
System.out.println("prop: " + prop);
```

The result is

```
prop: ??????????
```

The only solution seems to force the environment variable `LANG` in this way

```
pb.environment().put("LANG", "it_IT.UTF-8");
```

There are better solutions?
More portable?

### Updated at 20:30

Another solution seems to be adding the environment `LANG=it_IT.UTF-8` to the BASH script that launches the Eclipse process. But it is not something that I can control on every computer.

Comment: The answer is likely to lie in how the Eclipse Run Configuration invokes the child process. This is likely to depend on some combination of Eclipse, operating system and/or JRE versions.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` to the JVM.

Comment: That was what I thought but it does not solve the problem. I try to add the line `commands.add("-Dfile.encoding=UTF8");` or the line `commands.add("-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8");` but does not work. I always need to set the environment.

Comment: The problem could very well be the encoding of the parent JVM and/or the encoding of the file(s) containing the Java source where you are setting up the `ProcessBuilder`. Are you sure that you're using UTF8 **everywhere?** That is: make sure to actually save your Java source files as UTF8, as well as pass `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` to your initial JVM.

Comment: As I wrote the only solution I found in this moment is adding the environment `LANG=it_IT.UTF-8`, the `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` does not work. But it is the first time I have this problem? Can be something related to OSX?

Comment: As I commented, did you already make sure that the parent JVM and Java source are using UTF8?

Comment: No I cannot be sure. But what I want is to be able to launch a Java process using the UTF-8 even if the parent doesn't use it. However in the eclipse IDE I'm able to visualize the unicode strings in the launcher dialog, so what I expect is that if I put an unicode string in the VM args, the process launched, is able to read them.

Comment: `file.encoding` is not a standard JVM property and changing it is not generally supported. See [System.getProperties()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) for the only ones you can rely on, and don't expect them to be anything other than read-only. Not every internal API respects `file.encoding` even in the Sun JVM (unfortunately, the responses to defects raised around this disappeared with the majority of the sun.com content.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Eclipse Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) in Windows 10 and what it worked for me was:

> Control panel -> Regional settings -> Administrative tab-> Change system locale...

and setting the specific language I wanted to use (in my case, it was Greek)

Activating the Beta feature screwed things up so my setting is OFF